# IntelliJ OS X Services

Tags: macos, service, intellij-idea

I am using IntellJ IDEA 9.0.2 CE on OS X Snow Leopard. The Services menu never seems to contain any entries, even though I have installed several text services (which do show up in other applications). Is there a way to use these?

I am relatively new to the Mac.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to hack IntelliJ and contribute the code back to the community.

The Service menu, to be usable, needs a bit of support code in the app. If the app is built using Cocoa, the support is built in, but for a Java app it's not automatic.

To call Objective-C methods required to support the service menu from Java, you need to use [Rococoa](http://code.google.com/p/rococoa/). The Objective-C API concerning the service menu is described in [this Apple document](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/SysServices/introduction.html).